# How to esimate $X^{c}/c - \sum_{1 \leq t \leq X} t^{c-1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, elementary-number-theory, summation

Let $c > 0$. I am trying to obtain an upper bound for 
$$
|X^{c}/c - \sum_{1 \leq t \leq X} t^{c-1}|. 
$$
I am sure this is pretty small as $\int_{1}^X t^{c-1} dt = X^c/c - 1$. 
What is the best way to treat this when we have a sum instead?
Any comments/suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula)? Alternatively, write $$ \left| \frac{X^c}{c} - \sum_{t=1}^{X} t^{c-1} \right| = \left| \sum_{t=1}^{X} \left( \int_{t-1}^{t} u^{c-1} \, du - t^{c-1} \right) \right| $$ and applying Taylor approximation term-wise can be another option. In particular, this immediately yields the bound $\left| \frac{X^c}{c} - \sum_{t=1}^{X} t^{c-1} \right| \leq X^{c-1}$